# Protect static files hosted on Apache with Tomcat / Java

Tags: java, apache, spring-mvc, tomcat, authentication

I'm looking for a way to protect some static content hosted on Apache.
Those static files could be downloaded only by people based on rights that are defined in a database.

I am using Spring MVC for the web application.

I tried to forward the user to the relative path of the static content after I checked that the user has the appropriate rights. But it looks like forward in servlet can't forward to resource external to the Tomcat container. And I don't want to host the static content inside the web application folder.

I also tried to symlink a directory outside of the web application inside the web application folder. But again, it's not working.

The solutions I want to avoid is to redirect to the static content and then expose the actual URL of the resource on Apache which can then be access without any authorization.
I also don't want to use Tomcat to serve the static content with a servlet reading it blocks by blocks.

Comment: Look at .htaccess rules.  You should be able to insert .htaccess in the directory where the static content is housed, and assert appropriate access-privileges there.

Comment: Could the .htaccess be dynamic? All authorization rights are stored in a database